# Can Kubernetes be forced to restart a failed pod on a differet node?

Tags: kubernetes

When running a Kubernetes job I've set `spec.spec.restartPolicy: OnFailure` and `spec.backoffLimit: 30`. When a pod fails it's sometimes doing so because of a hardware incompatibility (matlab segfault on some hardware). Kubernetes is restarting the pod each time on the same node, having no chance of correcting the problem.

> Can I instruct Kubernete to try a different node on restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`restartPolicy`  only refers to restarts of the Containers by the Kubelet on the **same node**.
Setting  `restartPolicy: OnFailure`  will prevent the neverending creation of pods because it will just restart the failing one on the same node.

If you want to create new pods on failure with  `restartPolicy: Never`, you can limit them by setting  `activeDeadlineSeconds`  However pods also will be recreated on the same node as failed ones.  Upon reaching the deadline without success, the job will have status with reason: DeadlineExceeded. No more pods will be created, and existing pods will be deleted.

`.spec.backoffLimit`  is just the number of retries.

The Job controller recreates the failed Pods (associated with the Job) in an exponential delay. And of course, this delay time is set by the Job controller

Take a look: [pod-lifecycle](https://alibaba-cloud.medium.com/pod-lifecycle-container-lifecycle-hooks-and-restartpolicy-ab57f8e3ff35).

However  as a workaround you may want your Pods to end up on specific nodes which are properly working.

These scenarios are addressed by a number of primitives in Kubernetes:

- `nodeSelector`  — This is a simple Pod scheduling feature that allows scheduling a Pod onto a node whose labels match the  `nodeSelector`  labels specified
- `Node Affinity` —  is the enhanced version of the  `nodeSelector` which offers a more expressive syntax for fine-grained control of how Pods are scheduled to specific nodes.
  There are two types of affinity in Kubernetes: *node* affinity and *Pod* affinity. Similarly to `nodeSelector`, node affinity attracts a Pod to certain nodes, the Pod affinity attracts a Pod to certain Pods. In addition to that, Kubernetes supports Pod anti-affinity, which repels a Pod from other Pods.

Here's an example of a pod that uses node affinity:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-with-node-affinity
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/e2e-az-name
            operator: In
            values:
            - e2e-az1
            - e2e-az2
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - weight: 1
        preference:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: another-node-label-key
            operator: In
            values:
            - another-node-label-value
  containers:
  - name: with-node-affinity
    image: k8s.gcr.io/pause:2.0
```

This node affinity rule says the pod can only be placed on a node with a label whose key is `kubernetes.io/e2e-az-name` and whose value is either `e2e-az1` or `e2e-az2`. In addition, among nodes that meet that criteria, nodes with a label whose key is `another-node-label-key` and whose value is `another-node-label-value` should be preferred.
To label nodes you can use command:

```
$ kubectl label nodes <your-node-name> key=value
```

See definition: [scheduling-pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity).

As another workaround you may taint the specific, not working nodes - [taints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/) allow a Node to *repel* a set of Pods.

See more: [taint-nodes-kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/).

Taints get a possibility to mark a node as `NoSchedule` - pods by default cannot be spawned on this node until you will add `tolerations` to pods which will allow scheduler to create pods on nodes with taints specified in `toleration` configuration.  Command below:

```sh
$ kubectl taint nodes example-node key=value:NoSchedule
```

places a taint on node  `example-node`. The taint has key  `key`, value  `value`, and taint effect  `NoSchedule`. This means that no pod will be able to schedule onto  `node1`  unless it has a matching toleration.

See: [node-taint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51147847/kubernetes-the-hard-way-how-to-set-node-unschedulable/51153889).

Answer (score 3):

Once *Pod* is scheduled it cannot be moved to another *Node*.

The *Job* controller can create a new *Pod* if you specify `spec.spec.restartPolicy: Never`.
There is a chance that this new *Pod* will be scheduled on different *Node*.

I did a quick experiment with `podAntiAffinity:` but it looks like it's ignored by scheduler (makes sense as the previous Pod is in Error state).

BTW: If you can add labels to failing nodes it will be possible to avoid them by using `nodeSelector: <label>`.